# Installing Mysql Ruby gem on 64-bit CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, 64-bit, ruby, rubygems

I have a problem installing mysql ruby gem on 64bit CentOS machine.

```
[jacekb@vitaidealn ~]$ uname -a
Linux vitaidealn.local 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jun 10 18:51:06 EDT 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Mysql and mysql-devel packages are installed. Mysql_config provides following paths:

```
Usage: /usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
    --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv]
    --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
    --libs           [-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto]
    --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient_r -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto]
    --socket         [/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock]
    --port           [3306]
    --version        [5.0.45]
    --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqld -lz -lpthread -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lrt -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto]
```

Trying to install:

```
[jacekb@vitaidealn ~]$ gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-include=/usr/include/mysql --with-mysql-libs=/usr/lib64/mysql
...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-include=/usr/include/mysql --with-mysql-libs=/usr/lib64/mysql
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lm... no
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lz... no
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lsocket... no
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    checking for main() in -lnsl... no
    checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks for reading :).

Answer (score 5):

I think you need the devel package for the mysql-client. Try to install it with:

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: on my side mysql-devel was already installed but i also tried to reinstall it and it worked .

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.wzzrd.com/2008/02/building-mysql-gem-centos5-hell-usually.html) about this long ago. Sorry for plugging ;-)

The answer is to run

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-conf=/usr/bin/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/lib/mysql
```

You would have to use the lib64 path, obviously. Maybe this'll help you too.

You might want to know there is a ruby-mysql package in EPEL though. Might be interesting to look at that :)

Comment: +1 for pointing to EPEL.  Existing package management is almost always the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
1. yum uninstall mysql
2. yum install mysql
3. yum install mysql-devel (to install development libraries, For Debian, Knoppix, Buildix user apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev)
4. gem install mysql
```

Comment: why are you installing mysql two times ?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario it worked

```
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Comment: I tried. Didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: It worked for me without `sudo`.  I also had to remember to put the version number in (`gem install mysql -v2.7 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you described.  Managed to fix it by doing the following (as root of course):

`cd /usr/lib64`
`ln -nfs /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15 libmysqlclient.so`
`ldconfig`

After that I was able to simply run `gem install mysql` and it all just worked.

Hope this helps!